# C# Timer.Interval Pattern with 40ms?

Tags: c#, multithreading, image-processing

I'd like to use 3 or 4 [C# Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx) with an Interval that could be 40ms (to work with image data 1000/25 = 40).

According to MSDN it seems to be the good pattern to perform a Task every 40ms. The default interval is 100ms.

In real life, I'd like to know if 40ms is still Ok ? Or if I should use another thread design  pattern ? Is the wakeup/sleep behavior is near cpu free ?

Comment: How *precise* do you want it to be? Timers seem fine for this case… unless you’re trying to play video or something. What does the Task do? (In the case of video and such, you can use whatever timing mechanism you want — just make sure that what actually happens depends on `DateTime.Now` [er, make that a high-res timer independent of the clock] and not some counter.)

Comment: You'll get better answers if you show us your proposed code.

Comment: Thanks I got my answer, it was a designer pattern question. My use case is refactoring my code to perform QRCode, FaceRecognition, Skeleton Tracking, ... on Kinect ColorFrame data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special relevance to the 100 msec default, you can change it as needed.

You do need to pick your values carefully if you want to get an interval that's consistent from one machine to another.  The accuracy of the Timer class is affected by the default operating system clock interrupt rate.  On most Windows machines, that interrupt occurs 64 times per second.  Equal to 15.625 milliseconds.  There are machines that have a higher rate, some go as low as 1 msec.  A side-effect of other programs changing the interrupt rate.  The timeBeginPeriod() winapi function does this and it has a global effect.

So the best intervals to pick are ones that are a multiple of 15.625 and stay just below that.  So your chosen interval repeats well on any machine.  Which makes the good choices:

- 15
- 31
- 46
- 62
- etc.

Your best bet for aiming near 40 msec is therefore 46.  It will be accurate to 1.4% on any machine.  I do always pick 45 myself, nice round number.

Do beware that actual intervals can be arbitrary longer if the machine is under heavy load or you have a lot of active threadpool threads in your program.